# When i try to remove a row from the csv the file size is multipliying

Tags: python, csv

I want to create a program which generates numbers from 0 to 100000 and stores it in a file then, remove the numbers i give as input
I have done the code for generating the numbers and storing them in a csv file

```
import csv

nums = list(range(0,100000))
with open('codes.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for val in nums:
        writer.writerow([val])
```

and i tried to delete the row i wanted with this

```
import csv
import os

lines = list()
while True:
    members= input("Please enter a number to be deleted: ")

    with open('codes.csv', 'r') as readFile:
        reader = csv.reader(readFile)
        for row in reader:
            lines.append(row)
            for field in row:
                if field == members:
                    lines.remove(row)

    os.remove('codes.csv')

    with open('codes.csv', 'a+') as writeFile:
        writer = csv.writer(writeFile)
        writer.writerows(lines)
```

but the file size is multiplying each time i remove a number, please help

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but why add the line and then immediately remove it? Put the check before adding and simply don't add it.

Comment: You never clear `lines`, i.e. you write the lines over and over again to the same list.

Answer (score 0):

Add check before appending to your list, something like this should work:

```
with open('codes.csv', 'r') as readFile:
    reader = csv.reader(readFile)
    for row in reader:
        if all(field != members for field in row):
            lines.append(row)
```

Ps: don't forget to clear lines by adding `lines = []` at the beginning of the while loop (I assume you know what you're doing).

Comment: the number of empty rows between the numbers are increasing everytime i remove a number

Answer (score 0):

There a two problems:

1. The `lines` list is never cleared. Whenever a number is entered, everything is written again to `lines`.
2. When writing, the file is opened with the `a+` attributes, which means "append and update" file.

Try to recreate the list within the outer `while` loop and override the file contents by opening the file with attribute `w`, like this:

```
import csv
import os

while True:
    members= input("Please enter a number to be deleted: ")
    lines = list()

    with open('codes.csv', 'r') as readFile:
        reader = csv.reader(readFile)
        for row in reader:
            lines.append(row)
            for field in row:
                if field == members:
                    lines.remove(row)

    os.remove('codes.csv')

    with open('codes.csv', 'w') as writeFile:
        writer = csv.writer(writeFile)
        writer.writerows(lines)
```

Comment: i tried that but the file size is still multipliying

Comment: You open the file for writing with the `"a+"` attribute, which means "append" to file. Try `"w"` instead - this will override the contents of the existing file.

Comment: I tried your code still the file size is increasing, the number of empty rows between the numbers are increasing everytime i remove a number

Comment: The code is working for me. Whenever I remove one or more numbers, terminate the program, and look into the file, the removed number(s) aren't in anymore and there are no empty lines.

Comment: I tried it on another device it works fine, then what's wrong with my device?